# Why is Origin Access Identity user is not IAM managed?

Tags: amazon-web-services

According to the documentation, OAI (Origin Access Identity) is a "special CloudFront user that you can use to give CloudFront access to your Amazon S3 bucket". Whenever I think about AWS users, I think about them in terms of IAM users. However, this does not seems to be the case.

Is there any reason as to why AWS chose to use a different kind of user for CloudFront as opposed to IAM user/roles, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFront has been around [since 2008](http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/distribute-your-content-with-amazon-cloudfront/), but originally required that the bucket be public.

OAIs and CloudFront signed URLs became available [in 2009](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudfront-feature-private-content/).

IAM did not become generally available [until 2011](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/iam-identity-access-management/).

That is likely the best explanation available -- OAIs existed before IAM.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Each CloudFront distribution has ARN. instead of AWS inventing OAI, why not directly grant ARN in the S3 bucket policy?